Math help for a simple Chart
I have 5 horizontal lines and each has a distance of 30 px. The first horizontal line display the max value, the last the min value. Now I have an array with 13 items with different values. Basically I want show LINES (Chart) on the horizontal lines due the value of the array, for every item from the array.
I try to use what @Mina recommended me but it don't works correct.


      var prices = [];
  prices.push(28990, 30240, 30890, 32162, 31000, 31820, 31770, 30080, 28340, 28620, 28640, 27930, 28850);

  var minPrice = Math.floor(Math.min(...prices)/1000)*1000;
  var maxPrice = Math.ceil(Math.max(...prices)/1000)*1000;

  function addText(x, y, t) {
    var text = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg','text');
    
    text.setAttribute('x', x);     
    text.setAttribute('y', y); 
    text.setAttribute('fill', 'black');

    var textNode = document.createTextNode(t);
    text.appendChild(textNode);
    
    document.getElementById('main').appendChild(text);
  }
 
  function addLine(id, x1, y1, x2, y2, sc,sw) {
    const line = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg','line');
    
    line.setAttribute('id', id);
    line.setAttribute('x1', x1);
    line.setAttribute('y1', y1);
    line.setAttribute('x2', x2);
    line.setAttribute('y2', y2);
    line.setAttribute('stroke', sc);
    line.setAttribute('stroke-width', sw);

    document.getElementById("main").appendChild(line);
  }
  
  function addHorizontalLinesPrice() {
    var m = maxPrice;
    addText(20, 55, m);
    addText(20, 85, m = m-1500);
    addText(20, 115, m = m-1500);
    addText(20, 145, m = m-1500);
    addText(20, 175, m = m-1500);
  }
  
  addHorizontalLinesPrice();
  
  function addHorizontalLines() {
    var y = 50.5;
    
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      addLine("horizontalLine"+(i+1), 90, y, window.innerWidth-20, y, "black", 0.5);
      y = y + 30;
    }
  }
  
  addHorizontalLines();

  var totalHeight = 100;

  function getYPosition(price) {
      // How far the price is on the scale from minPrice to maxPrice
      var scale = (price - minPrice) / (maxPrice - minPrice);
      // Calculate y position based on the scale
      return totalHeight - (scale * totalHeight);
  }

  prices.forEach(price => {
      var x = 20;
      var yPos = getYPosition(price);
 
      addLine("", x, yPos, x+200, yPos, "green", 3);
      x = x + 100;
  });
      </script>
<svg id="main" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="800" height="220"></svg>




Please edit your question to provide more information. What is drawLine? "the LINES on the horizontal lines": it is not clear what you mean here. Do the capitals mean something specific? "add each item to the Horizontal Line": what does it mean to add an item on a line? Why in the example code you have used value 150? Where does that come from? Why in the next line it is 149? How does this match with the requirement of 50px? What is x1 or x2?

@trincot I edit my Post now it should be clearer, thanks.

This is a matter of getting the mapping right from your "world" coordinates to view coordinates.
I would suggest defining all the "magical numbers" -- that relate to coordinates on the web page -- to constants, so they have a meaningful name.
Here is a possible implementation:


// Define the "magic numbers" as constants:
const labelLeft = 20, labelTop = 55, 
      graphLeft = 90, graphTop = 50.5,
      graphWidth = window.innerWidth - graphLeft - 80,
      graphStep = 30, numLines = 5;

function addText(x, y, t) {
    const text = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg','text');
    text.setAttribute('x', x);     
    text.setAttribute('y', y); 
    text.setAttribute('fill', 'black');
    const textNode = document.createTextNode(t);
    text.appendChild(textNode);
    document.getElementById('main').appendChild(text);
}
 
function addLine(id, x1, y1, x2, y2, sc, sw) {
    const line = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'line');
    line.setAttribute('id', id);
    line.setAttribute('x1', x1);
    line.setAttribute('y1', y1);
    line.setAttribute('x2', x2);
    line.setAttribute('y2', y2);
    line.setAttribute('stroke', sc);
    line.setAttribute('stroke-width', sw);
    document.getElementById("main").appendChild(line);
}
  
function createMapping(prices) {
    const minPrice = Math.min(...prices);
    const maxPrice = Math.max(...prices);
    const step = (maxPrice - minPrice).toFixed(0).replace(/\B./g, "0") / (numLines - 1);
    let topPrice = (maxPrice + minPrice + step) / 2 + step * (numLines >> 1);
    return [topPrice - topPrice % step, step];
}

function drawLabelsAndLines(topPrice, step) {
    for (let i = 0; i < numLines; i++) {
        const y = graphTop + i * graphStep;
        addText(labelLeft, labelTop + i * graphStep, topPrice - i * step);
        addLine("horizontalLine"+(i+1), graphLeft, y, graphLeft + graphWidth, y, "black", 0.5);
    }
}

function drawValues(getYPosition, prices) {
    let x = graphLeft;
    let yPos = getYPosition(prices[0]);
    let stepX = graphWidth / (prices.length - 1);
    for (const price of prices.slice(1)) {
        addLine("", x, yPos, x += stepX, yPos = getYPosition(price), "green", 3);
    }
}

function drawGraph(prices) {
    const [topPrice, step] = createMapping(prices);
    drawLabelsAndLines(topPrice, step);
    drawValues(price => graphTop + (topPrice - price) / step * graphStep, prices);
}

// demo
const prices = [28990, 30240, 30890, 32162, 31000, 31820, 31770, 30080, 28340, 28620, 28640, 27930, 28850];
drawGraph(prices);
<svg id="main" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="800" height="220"></svg>




Thank you very much! This helps me to understand how it can work.

You need to determine these aspects.

The range ( which is the difference between the maximum and minimum values )
Scaling factor (  This will help in mapping each price to a corresponding position on your chart )
Determine the Y position for each line.

var prices = [13000, 11000, 14000, 10000];

var maxPrice = Math.max(...prices);
var minPrice = Math.min(...prices);


var totalHeight = 4 * 50;


function getYPosition(price) {
    // How far the price is on the scale from minPrice to maxPrice
    var scale = (price - minPrice) / (maxPrice - minPrice);
    // Calculate y position based on the scale
    return totalHeight - (scale * totalHeight);
}


prices.forEach(price => {
    var yPos = getYPosition(price);
    drawLine(50, yPos, 150, yPos);
});


Thank you very much! I try use what you write but unfortunately it don't works correct. See the Post above your answer
